# Recommendations for Java + OpenPGP?

Tags: java, cryptography, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I want to develop a small OpenPGP client and I'm searching for a Java library for OpenPGP.

Are there any (open source) recommendations for this approach?

[Cryptix.org](http://www.cryptix.org/) does not seem alive anymore...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) library, for Java and C#. I haven't any experiences with it. I will try it and report here.

It provides:

1. A lightweight cryptography API for Java and C#.
2. A provider for the Java Cryptography Extension and the Java Cryptography Architecture.
3. A clean room implementation of the JCE 1.2.1.
4. A library for reading and writing encoded ASN.1 objects.
5. A light weight client-side TLS API.
6. Generators for Version 1 and Version 3 X.509 certificates, Version 2 CRLs, and PKCS12 files.
7. Generators for Version 2 X.509 attribute certificates.
8. Generators/Processors for S/MIME and CMS (PKCS7/RFC 3852).
9. Generators/Processors for OCSP (RFC 2560).
10. Generators/Processors for TSP (RFC 3161).
11. Generators/Processors for OpenPGP (RFC 4880).
12. A signed jar version suitable for JDK 1.4-1.6 and the Sun JCE.

(from BouncyCastle.org)

Comment: what were the results of your experimentation?

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial library on top of BouncyCastle: http://www.didisoft.com/ which greatly simplifies the BouncyCastle API.

I have not tried it just found it mentioned on jGuru.

I think it's safe to go with BouncyCastle alone. Their library is under development and they provider openpgp examples...

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: our SecureBlackbox (Java edition) includes [OpenPGP components for Java and Android](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-pgp.php), much richer than in BouncyCastle, and with support, samples and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's [PGPJava](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~jampen/pgpjava/index.html), but it's pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [PGPainless](https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless) which is also based on Bouncycastle, and scores pretty good on the [OpenPGP Interoperability Test Suite](https://tests.sequoia-pgp.org/).